# Change Vendor Name returned from IP scanning apps

Tags: networking, network-interface

I have a custom embedded device that returns a Chinese vendor name when IP apps scan the network (and I mean that actual Vendor name, not the hostname).

Since this is an embedded device for a custom system Id like to change the vendor name to our actual company name. How can we do this running Ubuntu 22.04?

EDIT: The name these apps query for this is called the "MAC Vendor" field, so guess that is what needs to be changed in the OS

Answer (score 3):

The [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is hardwired in the NIC.

However, there exists a tool called `macchanger` which can change this in software (if the NIC supports it, that is): https://github.com/alobbs/macchanger

Check your package manager, maybe it's included.

The first three bytes of the MAC address are used to indicate the vendor of the device or NIC, known as "organizationally unique identifier" (OUI), so you only need to change those. [Here](https://gist.github.com/aallan/b4bb86db86079509e6159810ae9bd3e4) is a list of known vendors and their MAC prefixes.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1120178/how-to-register-for-a-vendor-oui-mac-address-prefix

Comment: So these app then just use the OUI and lookup the company name from that? It's not a string that can be changed on the OS itself. Looks like you need to register to obtain one.